# Nesting of form using contolvalueaccessor

Tags: angular, controlvalueaccessor

I have a one container component and two child component : trip and component.
To nest the child component in parent , i have implemented Controlvalueaccessor. I have created a abstractvalueaccessor class which implements Controlvalueaccessor and then other components(trip & contact) are extending it.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dfxwde

```
export class ContactComponent extends AbstractValueAccessor<ContactInfoModel>{

    contactInfo: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
        email: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
        phone: new FormControl("",[Validators.required])
    });

}

export class TripComponent extends AbstractValueAccessor<any>{

  tripInfo: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
      from: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
      to: new FormControl("",[Validators.required])
  });

  trip="";
}
```

I am able to achieve the nesting of form value when I am separately implementing CVA in each component because I'm able to play with formgroup value but not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You are not implementing `ControlValueAccessor`, see this: [How to implement custom FormControl](https://alligator.io/angular/custom-form-control/)